# Is there a way to use both the PEN and TOUCH together on Windows "POINTER" API?

Tags: c++, windows, multi-touch

Windows 10 when you use the "POINTER" api for a "unified" way of getting input from all pointing devices has some quirks.

Some for good design reasons but it does not serve all cases.

They disable touch input when the stylus or pen is being used.  Not a HW issue.

So if I want to drag the space with a finger while I am drawing a line with the pen, can't do that or hold down a button while using the pen etc.

Is there a way to turn off the "disable touch while pen is down" "feature" in the windows 10 API ?? so I can get simultaneous input from both ?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this works for sure with RAWINPUT, but then you'll need to implement parsing for the raw touchscreen digitizer input data for every device that you want to support.

I'm still researching myself if there is another API that will allow you to receive the unfiltered touch events in a device-independent format.

Comment: I ended up using the windows 10 "unified pointer API" which basically works but has a few bugs and inconsistencies between different devices.  Such as different enter/exit display/window behavior between mouse and touch.